# pList in documents folder - need it in with project

Tags: objective-c, macos

At the moment I can only access my pList if it is in my user/documents folder, how can I make the pList part of the project instead (I'm using Xcode 4), I am using command line to test the theory but I would like to incorporate it into an app. Do I need to add it to the build?

```
//=================GET FILE PATH FOR PLIST
NSError *error;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); //1  Create a list of paths.
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"mypList.plist"]; //3

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath: path])
{
    NSString *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mypList" ofType:@"plist"]; //5

    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:bundle toPath: path error:&error];   }
}


 //==================READ PLIST
NSMutableDictionary *savedStock = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: path];

NSLog(@"%@", savedStock);

[savedStock release];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make it part of the app the best way would be copy the file into the project.

Comment: yes thanks, I have seen the best place is to add to the Supporting Files section.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to read it in your app add it to the project and it will then be part of the bundle (so you should be able to locate it within the code regardless of wherever .app file is launched).

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
```

should point you roughly in the right direction...

If you wish to write back to it then you should get the app to test for it's existence in the applications library folder (user/Library/your_application_name - there are methods in the OSX libraries to locate the library folder) if it doesn't exist then load it from the bundle and upon quit/exit/save/change etc write it back to the appropriate applications library folder.

This might help also...

```
NSString *libraryFolderPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
```